# Nesting structure in linear mixed model

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis

I have data with a nesting structure I am unsure how to account for.
I have data on countries, who were rated by two different organizations, once per year each. I would like to know what country specific factors influence the ratings and observe if these predictors have different effects on the rating from each organization.
So I do have two outcome values (rows) per country and year, one for each organization, over 10 years. How do I nest that?

My intuition says to nest countries in time and just control for the organization with a fixed effect. I could also use country and time both as random intercepts and use a random intercept for organization on level three.
I do have an expectation that there is variance between organizations and between countries, time is not so much a factor. I need to account for repeated mesures though. I also considered running two separate analyses, one for each organization, then I do not have the problem of having the organization as additional nesting structure. Then I would probably just use country and time each with a random intercept.
I have at this point confused myself and need some help.